# Generated pdf letter not associated to a case

Tags: lightning

Is it possible to create report in Salesforce to pull generated pdf letters that are not associate with a case? For example, when we delete a case, it seems like the generated pdf letter are not always deleted and we need to delete the letter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.